# How to initialize your backbone app within require.js after external callback

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

Normally you load in an Backbone App using require.js during page load

```
<script data-main="js/main" src="js/libs/require/require.js"></script>
```

which loads some dependencies, and launches the app.

If your app requires manipulation of the DOM, you can use the domReady plugin

```
require(['domReady','app' ], function (domReady, App) {
  domReady(function (App) {
     App.Initialize()
  }):
});
```

But my application communicates with a Flash API. I need to wait till the flash plugin is done loading it's own xml. I fire a callback back to javascript when this is done. This callback needs to fire the app.initialize() with the dependencies as in require.js

The first method and second method (waiting for dom) doesn't ensure the flash api is available yet. So how can I Initialize the app, so that app.js has its dependencies and the flash api is available. Or formulated differently: How can I initialize require.js through a javascript event/callback

**Update:**
Apparently, this would suffice:

```
<script data-main="js/main" src="js/libs/require/require.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function init(){
        require(['framework/app'], function(App){
          App.initialize();
        });
    }       
</script>
```

The flash plugin can just call window.init() to start the app. Downside would be that stuff like jQuery gets loaded when the app gets initialized. This could lead intoo a small delay before stuff shows.

I eonder if, when I load jquery in the head/end of body, require.js would reload/instantiate another copy of jquery, or read from cache/dom

Answer (score 1):

You could take advantage of requirejs shim config, which will allow you to define a 'export' for specified require modules.  This export will be the value cached on the global context and would be available as the callback function to use:

```
<script data-main="js/main" src="js/libs/require/require.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    requirejs.config({
        shim: {
            'framework/app': {
                exports: 'App'
            }
        }
    });
    require(['framework/app'], function(App){});
</script>
```

From here, your code that calls back a javascript function can just call:

```
App.initialize();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, although it's been two years :) I can't really test it if it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a lot (actually anything) about Flash in the browser, but if there is a way to detect with JavaScript that Flash has loaded:

1. Make Flash change a JavaScript global variable
2. Make Flash add an attribute to some elements

Then you can create a JavaScript function that checks this condition (every 1 second for example) and initialize the app once the check is validated. Use `setInterval(function, time)` to create this function. Make sure you clear the interval after loading your app, to ensure it doesn't load again.